# How to make sharing possible between two different subnet computers

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, subnet

I have USB drive Internet on my one laptop and I have enable the ICS on that and from LAN of laptop I am asharing Internet with router, which then used by other laptops

The static ip of Laptop LAN is 192.168.137.1

The ip which my router gets is 192.168.137.2

Now then my router has gateway ip 192.168.2.1

And other computer from router get ip 192.168.2.4

I have shared the folder on original laptop, how can I access that from computer after the router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't tried mounting a drive through a router (my previous office had no problems with computers on a wireless router printing to printers on the wired LAN the router had been plugged into), you *should* be able to use Map Network Drive and specify the laptop by IP address from the computer. For instance `\\192.168.137.1\folder` should work.  This will only work from the "inside" of the router to the "outside" since most consumer class routers also act as firewalls.

Your setup would be ideal if you had a switch (or if this was wireless, an [Access Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point) without a router) rather than a router, this would allow the other computers to appear on the same network as the laptop.  You can fake it by attaching the laptop to the "inside" of the router rather than the "internet" side and disabling the router's DHCP service.  Computers connecting to the router should then get an IP in the 192.168.137.x network and the 192.168.137.1 gateway from ICS directly.

If this is a wireless router, be warned: if try this with your laptop connected to your router wirelessly, you'll have half the wireless bandwidth because each packet will have to be sent twice: from the computer to the router then the router to the laptop.  If your wireless router has LAN ports for the inside network, that would avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your LAN and WLAN networks are on different subnets..

My suggestion is that inside your router you should be able to

1.) Add a static route to join the networks

or

2.) Use the same network on both LAN & WLAN to make your life easy..

Comment: 1)How can i add static route 2) if tried setting the routergateway adress like 192.168.137.4 so that clients get the ips like 192.168.137.8 but then my internet is not working

Answer (score 0):

are all 192.168.* networks unroutable? or just 192.168.1? maybe your router needs to do some NAT to make it appear on the other subnet.

Answer (score 0):

If it crosses NAT, PAT will need to be configured (recommend against this since it will expose your smb services)

If it connects directly to the internet, internet routers will drop packets with a private IP destination.

Best to connect the two sites via a vpn.

I suspect this question may be best asked in superusers.