# HOw to make two computers with different internet access each others network share

Tags: windows, internet, share

I have two different computers on is having ADSL internet coming from other company and i also have 2 LAN cxards on that computer.

The other computer is getting internet via USB dongle.

Now as they both are in same room .
Is there any way that i access the each others resource without going through internet.
I mean by joining some cable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add extra NICs to other computer too and connect them using cross-over cable. Use private addressing 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 or 192.168.0.0/16 on the interface through which the computers are connected to each other. You should easily get 100mbps to gigabit connectivity and Internet wont get used.

Comment: I have extra NIC on computer 1 . but not on laptop . but i have router attached from LAN port of laptop. Can i join one of ethernet port of router with computer 1 LAN

Comment: Yes joining router port with ethernet port of computer 1 would allow them to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to join the two computers with a cable.  There are two things to think about:

1. **Type of Ethernet cable.** You can connect the two computers with a [crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable).  This eliminates the need to use a switch or hub between the two machines.  Note that some newer computers, including all Apple computers made within the past 4 years (possibly longer), do not require special crossover cables at all.  They auto-detect when they are connected to another computer with a straight-through cable and perform the crossover automatically.
2. **IP address selection.** You can set each computer to use a static [RFC 1918](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html) addresses (most typically 192.168.x.x), making sure that the two computers share a subnet. Or, if you leave DHCP enabled, the two computers are likely to come online with random [APIPA](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CDEQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Faa505918.aspx&ei=vprXTKfZEZGWsgP5wtSNCw&usg=AFQjCNElLtlxSD8ne9Zl66W2zhBP1T-WAg) addresses (169.254.x.x).  Each computer will then have two IP addresses: the public one that it gets from its ISP (for internet access), and a private address for the dedicated link between the two computers.

Answer (score 0):

if your two computer are on a lan, there should be no reason they can't contact each other. Providing that they are on the same subnet and do not have conflicting IPs

Comment: They are not on LAn , they have interent from different companies one on LAN port and other using USB mobile internet

Comment: The easiest method is to create a vpn connecting the two sites, imo.

Comment: I think this is a candidate for migration to SuperUser.

Comment: I was just thinking that, looking at the duplicate question here http://serverfault.com/questions/199228/how-to-make-sharing-possible-between-two-different-subnet-computers

Comment: if i make the VPN then will my main internet will still work and i can access the files on share. Basically on one computer i am downloading movies using unlimited internet with slow speed and on other computer i am doing my office work with fast but limited internet. i just to watch the movies downloaded from computer one on computer2. As they are in same room . I just want the speed should be good like on LAN.VPN will make it slow as it will happen through internet

Comment: see split horizon. They are in the same room??? Create lan between the two. Cross-over cable with static ip for the least expensive and simplest option.